# How to execute a javascript function before update panel updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, submit

I'd like to run a jQuery function BEFORE an update panel is fired for refreshing. As this refresh can be done with any of many buttons and other ways, I was hoping to use the submit handler or something like that, but it did not work.

I tried this to attach the event to the main form:

```
jQuery('form').submit(function () { alert('submit!'); });
```

and also this to attach to the update panel

```
jQuery('#pnlContent').submit(function () { alert('submit!'); });
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: The `UpdatePanel` form isn't "submitted" in the normal sense. It is "submitted" via ajax so those event will not fire.

Comment: @Chad so what could I use in stead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me. Got the idea [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=256). Basically, you define a function to run before the update, and a function to run afterwards. Then you register those functions to run with the page request manager.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Put your code to run before UpdatePanel begins async postback here */
    function beforeAsyncPostBack() {
        var curtime = new Date();
        alert('Time before PostBack:   ' + curtime);           
    }

    /* Put your code to run after UpdatePanel finishes async postback here */
    function afterAsyncPostBack() {
        var curtime = new Date();           
        alert('Time after PostBack:    ' + curtime);
    }

    /* Don't mess with any of the below code */
    Sys.Application.add_init(appl_init);

    function appl_init() {
        var pgRegMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        pgRegMgr.add_beginRequest(beforeAsyncPostBack);
        pgRegMgr.add_endRequest(afterAsyncPostBack);
    }      
</script>
```

Comment: It seems the event is not triggered for AutoPostBack, is there another event for that?

Comment: @Psddp It should be. But if you're dealing with UpdatePanel and having to hack around like this, then I highly suggest you rethink your entire strategy and ditch the UpdatePanel. You'll spend far less time rewriting it than you will fixing all the UpdatePanel and Web Forms nonsense.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can use onsubmit="return check();" in form. it will check this function before submit form like this.

```
function check(){
   // do javascript code
   // after check your javascript
   document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
}
```

HTML :

```
<form id="frm1" action="#" onsubmit="return check();">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function PageLoad()
{
    if (!window.Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack())
    {
        window.Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest( AjaxEnd );
        window.Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest( AjaxBegin );
    }
}

function AjaxEnd()
{
    alert("AjaxEnd");
}

function AjaxBegin()
{
    alert("AjaxBegin");
}
```